# Some navigation links work, others don't. Relative URL path?

Tags: css, url, navigation

I'm just getting started with HTML and CSS and I can't figure out why some navigation links don't work. I'm building a basic website and the files are served on my local C drive under a folder called 'shirley'. Inside this folder I have:

-index.html (landing page)
-styles.css
-an img folder with pictures
-a folder called contact with another index.html / styles.css file in it
-a folder called department, same as above
-a folder called regulations, same as above

The navigation bar is set out as HOME  DEPARTMENT  REGULATIONS  CONTACT
When I open index.html in the browser, I can click on HOME and DEPARTMENT and I'm taken to the right page. However clicking on REGULATIONS AND CONTACT shows a 'this webpage was not found error'.

I think the problem is in the url shown in the browser, which is
file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/department/regulations.html
and 
file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/department/contact.html

and should be 
file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/regulations/index.html
and
file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/contact/index.html

I have **NO IDEA** where the browser is picking up this address. This is the code I have in the navigation section of the landing page:

```
<ul>
<li><a class="nav" href="./index.html">Home</a></li> <!-- ===./ for root index to link back to itself=== -->
<li><a class="nav" href="department/index.html">Department</a></li>
<li><a class="nav" href="regulations/index.html">Regulations</a></li>
<li><a class="nav" href="contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
```

Any ideas? I'm losing my mind over this :-(

Comment: I'm guessing you've closed the <ul> tag properly but didn't include it in the snippet?tanandtech.com

Comment: Clear your browser cache.

Comment: Yes, the <ul> tag is closed in index.html. I also cleared my cache and tried different browsers before posting, but the problem persists.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess you stepped into the trap that most of the beginners in web coding do.
First, you don't use a local webserver like XAMPP. Although it's not really necessary for HTML-only websites, it has real benefits to use in development. If you plan to learn PHP you will need it anyway.

Second, you are using directories, which are not handled very well without a webserver and proper knowledge. As you already expirienced, the correct notation of the URL is very important. So, like Mike already stated, making the links absolute will help.
But the problem then is, before uploading to a real webserver, you have to clean up all the links. A tedious and unnecessary action.

The solution is: don't use directories for content. While it's OK to use folders for images, scripts, CSS and so on, it's almost never needed, to store content pages into directories. Just use the name of the category as filename like:

```
department.html
regulations.html
contact.html
```

If you need some subpages in this categories, just add them with a dash like:

```
department-office.html
department-accounting.html
...
```

This way you have a clean and readable filenaming.

Comment: Thanks. You mean that I should rename all the index files as per their category and keep them in the root?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It will make life easier.

Comment: Thank you, that worked! Well, partially...Now 3 of the links work but I can't navigate to "Contact". The browser shows this address file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/shirley/contact/index.html, which is obviously wrong, as the file has been renamed. Any ideas why this is happening?

Comment: As you use HTML only I assume you have the navigation on every single (sub)page. And you need to change it on every page when edited. A further drawback when using HTML only.
So I guess you have still a wrong link on some page in your navigation.

Answer (score 0):

Use absolute URLs, for example (depending on your structure):

```
<ul>
    <li><a class="nav" href="./index.html">Home</a></li> <!-- ===./ for root index to link back to itself=== -->
    <li><a class="nav" href="/department/index.html">Department</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="/regulations/index.html">Regulations</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="/contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

For example, what may be happening is you are going to /department/index.html, so now you are in the directory /department.

If you have a relative URL like `regulations/index.html`, it is now going to look for a regulations directory in the department directory.

Using absolute URLs means that it always starts from the root.

Comment: Ok, so I tried that and then I wasn't able to see any of the links, so I changed it back to what I had before, where at least I was directed correctly to 2 of the 4 links. This is odd because using the original code I can get to HOME and DEPARTMENT, but not to the other two tabs.

Comment: What is the directory at the root of your website? What is the directory structure from there?

Comment: This is how it appears: http://imgur.com/5Gn0OD7 . Each folder except for img has an index.html file.

Answer (score 0):

Does this issue always occur from the initial index page? If you have the same code snippets on the nested index.html files, perhaps the nested pages are attempting to look for the folders in their own directories.

EG:

1. I enter "file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/index.html" into the address bar.
   Result: The parent page displays with the other links displayed properly.
2. I click on the "Regulations" link.
   Result: It takes me to "file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/regulations/index.html" properly.
3. Now, on the Regulations page, I click another link -- IE, ./index or ./contact/index.
   Result: If I click the ./index.html link, it *stays* on the Regulations page, because it's looking in the current directory. If I click on ./contact/index.html, it fails because contact isn't a child of Regulations.

Just an idea. If this is the case, you can fix it by making the links explicit:

```
    <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/index.html">Home</a></li> <!-- ===./ for root index to link back to itself=== -->
    <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/department/index.html">Department</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/regulations/index.html">Regulations</a></li>
    <li><a class="nav" href="file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/contact/index.html">Contact</a></li>
```

Comment: Thanks, I tried making the links explicit and I get the same results (i.e."Home" and "Department" are displayed properly but not "Regulations" and "Contact"). I also have the same problem if I open /regulations/index.html directly on the browser. I can get to "Home" and "Department" from there but I can't 'link the page back to itself' (don't know how to explain it) or get it to display "Contact".

Comment: Does it work if you type in the address manually? IE, enter the explicit URL for regulations into your address bar?

Comment: Yes, it does in both cases. I just can't figure out why clicking on the link elicits the incorrect URL, for example file:///C:/Users/MYNAME/Desktop/shirley/department/regulations.html. Why is the index.html file replaced by regulations.html? This file doesn't exist. Also, why is it looking into "department" when the <ul><li> list specifies another path? Sooo annoying!

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem like this before. The problem is you are missing one dot.
Change

```
<li><a class="nav" href="./index.html">Home</a></li>
```

for

```
<li><a class="nav" href="../index.html">Home</a></li>
```

Comment: Relative path is: links up one directory are listed as ../folder

Comment: Hi there, I tried that and then I can open "Home" and navigate from there to "Department", but then I can't get back to "Home", and I still can't navigate to "Contact" or "Regulations".